# My Activity comes out as a Blank even though it shouldn't?

Tags: java, android

I'm a complete beginner with coding and decided to try out android studios for fun without having formal training or lessons for the basics so I'm sorry if this seems like a dumb problem but whenever I try to run my code it just comes off as blank? Any idea how to solve this?

Here's a screenshot of what comes up

[image]

```
package com.example.trtalpha17;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

public class Register_Tutor extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String[] SCHOOLS = new String[]{
         
            "A", "B", "C"
    };

    private static final String[] COURSE = new String[]{
            "Bachelor of Science in Social Work (BS Social Work)",
            "Bachelor of Science in Marine Transportation (BSMT)",
            "Bachelor of Science in Food Technology (BS Food Tech)",
            "Bachelor of Science in Nutrition and Dietetics (BS Nutrition and Dietetics)"
    };

    private static final String[] EDUCA = new String[]{
            "Grade 9", "Grade 10", "Grade 11", "Grade 12", "1st Year College", "2nd Year College", "3rd Year College", "4th Year College", "5th Year College", "Graduate"
    };


    private static final String[] TITLES = new String[]{
            "Mr.", "Ms.", "Mrs.", "Mx."
    };


    EditText metEmail, metPhone, metPassword, metPasswordconfirm, metNamefirst, metNamelast;
    Button mbutton;
    ProgressBar progressBar2;
    FirebaseAuth fAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register_tutor2);




        final AutoCompleteTextView metTitle = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.etTitle);
        final AutoCompleteTextView mautoCompleteTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView);
        final AutoCompleteTextView meduc = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.educ);
        final AutoCompleteTextView metcourse = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.etcourse);

        metTitle.setThreshold(2);
        mautoCompleteTextView.setThreshold(1);
        meduc.setThreshold(1);
        metcourse.setThreshold(1);

        ImageView marrow = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.arrow);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapterarrow = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, TITLES);
        metTitle.setAdapter(adapterarrow);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapterschools = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, SCHOOLS);
        mautoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(adapterschools);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapteredu = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, EDUCA);
        meduc.setAdapter(adapteredu);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adaptercourse = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, COURSE);
        metcourse.setAdapter(adaptercourse);


        marrow.setOnClickListener(new  View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                metTitle.showDropDown();
            }
        });

        metNamefirst = findViewById(R.id.etNamefirst);
        metNamelast = findViewById(R.id.etNamelast);
        metEmail = findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
        metPhone =findViewById(R.id.etPhone);
        metPassword = findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
        metPasswordconfirm =findViewById(R.id.etPasswordconfirm);
        mbutton = findViewById(R.id.button);
        progressBar2 = findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
        fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        if(fAuth.getCurrentUser() != null){
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));
            finish();
        }



        mbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String email = metEmail.getText().toString().trim();
                String password = metPassword.getText().toString().trim();

                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
                    metEmail.setError("Email is required.");
                    return;
                }

                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
                    metPassword.setError("Password is required.");
                    return;
                }

                if(password.length()<6){
                    metPassword.setError("Password length must be at least 6 characters.");
                    return;
                }



                fAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull @NotNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            Toast.makeText(Register_Tutor.this, "Registration complete.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));

                        }else {
                            Toast.makeText(Register_Tutor.this, "There was an error making your that request. Please try again later." + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    }
                });
            }

        });
    }
}
```

> **LAYOUT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Register_Tutor">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:fontFamily="cursive"
        android:text="Register as a Tutor"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2">

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/etTitle"
            android:layout_width="68dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_baseline_person_24"
            android:drawablePadding="5dp"
            android:hint="Title"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/arrow"
            android:layout_width="16dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:drawablePadding="5dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/outline_arrow_drop_down_black_18" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etNamefirst"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:hint="First name"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etNamelast"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:hint="Last name"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />
    </TableRow>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tableRow">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etEmail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_baseline_email_24"
            android:drawablePadding="5dp"
            android:hint="Email address"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etPhone"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_baseline_local_phone_24"
            android:drawablePadding="5dp"
            android:hint="Phone number"
            android:inputType="phone" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linear1">

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:completionThreshold="1"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_baseline_school_24"
            android:drawablePadding="5dp"
            android:hint="School" />

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/educ"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:completionThreshold="1"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_baseline_article_24"
            android:drawablePadding="5dp"
            android:hint="Educational Attainment" />

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/etcourse"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:completionThreshold="1"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_baseline_article_24"
            android:drawablePadding="5dp"
            android:hint="Course" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linear2">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_baseline_lock_24"
            android:drawablePadding="5dp"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etPasswordconfirm"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_baseline_lock_open_24"
            android:drawablePadding="5dp"
            android:hint="Confirm Password"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="SIGN UP"
            android:textColorHint="#FDFCFC"
            app:backgroundTint="#315E8C" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

> **ANDROID MANIFEST**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.trtalpha17">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.TRTAlpha17"
        >

        <activity android:name=".Register_Tutor">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Login" />
        <activity android:name=".RegisterStudent" />
        <activity android:name=".RegistrationHome" />

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: I don't know android, but I do know Java, and this, *"... and decided to try out android studios for fun without having formal training or lessons for the basics..."* is probably not the best way to attack learning Android programming or programming in general. Better to learn at least some basics of Java first through a tutorial, lesson, or book. Else, you are setting yourself up for some significant frustration.

Comment: Is there any error in logcat??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you clean and rebuild your project or Invalid caches/restart from IDE?You will find it in under File menu.

It seems like your code is fine , so I decided to run in IDE its compiling and running perfectly .

[image]

Firebase console-

[image]

So you can do some checks in your side -
1.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_register_tutor2);
```

is layout.activity_register_tutor2 your main/default layout? Or any other layout`?

2.

```
if(fAuth.getCurrentUser() != null){
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
```

If you already sign in at least one time , this code will take you in MainActivity . Is that blank activity MainActivity? Make sure . You did not share your layout file of MainActivity , so I'm not sure .

You can Implement logout to test/debug your app easier by -

```
    private Button mLogOutBtn;
    mLogOutBtn = findViewById(R.id.log_out_btn);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    mLogOutBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mAuth.signOut();
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Register_Tutor.class));
            finish();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Oh my gosh I hadn't realized it already moved on to the main activity cause I signed in long before I made any major changes to the registration as a trial to see if it would work. So appreciative of your time and effort, thanks a bunch!